# If a component is used in 2 places in Angular is it downloaded 2 times?

Tags: angular

Have a component inside other components or modules in an angular application, is it re-downloaded when inside a different module? Or does angular understand that it's the same component and doesn't re-download it?

Comment: No, it is downloaded once as a part of an initial bundle you created or lazily loaded module. But if you have used it twice on the page, the angular framework internally creates an instance of that component two times.

Answer (score -1):

No multiple downloads, unless you explicitly do that yourself! You can check your package.json to verify only a single version of any package is installed in your project.